# Which one better to writing in a try catch block Specific exception or generic Exception?

Tags: java, exception

I am trying to write code with exception handling but, I have one concern about which one is good to write in try catch block **"Specific Exception"** or **"Generic Exception"**.

Performance wise which one is better.

Kindly help me with suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @raviraja I am not asking the difference between specific vs generic, I am asking about which one better with performance.

Comment: did you read the accepted answer for that question? it clearly explains what is good and what is bad.

Comment: @raviraja, I was not expecting this answer. I am expecting performance wise answer.

Comment: @Sushant the performance of exceptions is terrible anyway. The difference in the performance - if any at all - is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to go for Specific exception handling. Coding in this direction makes sure developer knows possibly which exceptions can be thrown beforhand.

Another benefit is one can take action specific to a Exception type, rather than having a single catch block and handle Exception in generic way.